# Is the time complexity of the following cases correct?

Tags: time-complexity

I am a bit confused about the (average case) time complexity of the following cases:

I have N=3 arrays, each with different number of elements:

1. Array1 has n1 elements
2. Array2 has n2 elements
3. Array3 has n3 elements

- Case A: I perform quicksort on each array in a sequential manner, starting from the first array till the last.

  In this case the time complexity will be N*O(nlogn) (where n is the generalized form of the number of elements of an array) or O(n1logn1 + n2logn2 + n3logn3), which asymptotically is equal to O(max(n1logn1, n2logn2, n3logn3))?
- Case B: I perform quicksort on each array in parallel.
  In this case the time complexity will be O(max(n1logn1, n2logn2, n3logn3))?
- Case C: There is a 50% chance of performing quicksort (on all arrays, in parallel) and 50% chance of not sorting any array.

  Isn't this case essentially the same as case B? I.e.  0.5 * O(max(n1logn1, n2logn2, n3logn3)), which asymptotically is equal to O(max(n1logn1, n2logn2, n3logn3))?

Therefore, all cases have the same time complexity, O(max(n1logn1, n2logn2, n3logn3))?

Comment: Big-O notation is generally used to express worst-case complexity, which is not necessarily the same as 'average' complexity. What you should learn from this, I think, is that big-O is a nice tool, but it offers only a rather rough analysis of the run-time characteristics of an algorithm.

Comment: I meant average case of quicksort which is O(nlogn).

Comment: @NWouda That's a misconception. Big O notation is used to give an upper bound for a function, and the function could measure worst case, average case, best case or anything else; the function doesn't even have to describe anything about an algorithm, and you can still use big O notation to give an upper bound for it.

Comment: O(max(a,b)) = O(a+b) in general when the functions are non-negative. All three cases are the same, asymptotically.

Comment: @kaya3 you're right, of course, but that was not the point I was trying to make. My point is that these three cases all share the same asymptotic big-O complexity, yet behave very differently in practice. There are cost functions for time complexity estimates that do differentiate these three cases, but big-O is not one of them. At least not without some refinement.

Comment: Thank you both for your valuable comments!